# Hide "From"/Deployment URL in Clickone Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce, publish

Is it possible to hide the url of where the deployment path is whenever clickonce is installing or updating the installation package to a client computer ? i am trying to prevent the user from knowing where the application is published so that they would not access it without prior permissions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't hide that. You can create a customer installer where you call `VSTOInstaller` (for VSTO addins) for example yourself, in silent mode.

There is no way to configure the default ClickOnce installer in the way you ask. Besides that, it would be useless since monitoring traffic is very easy and will reveal the location anyway.